# Dynamic drop down creation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind, asp.net-4.0

I have a table with 3 columns

> ```
>  EmployeeId     EmployeeName      ReportingTo                       
>         1            A
>         2            B                  1
>         3            C                  1
>         4            D                  1
>         5            E                  2
>         6            F                  3
>         7            I                  3
>         8            J                  4
>         9            K                  8
> ```

Employee Ids are unique. ReportingTo is id of person to whom employee is reporting. ReportingTo is null means A is Boss.

In Asp.net, I want to create a page with one dropdownlist by default. In that dropdownlist EmployeeId whose reportingto is null will be loaded. when I select that dropdown with EmployeeId 1 then next dropdownlist will get created & fill with employees who are reporting to EmployeeId 1.

I have created this whole page, but for that i am generating dropdownlist manually in aspx page.

Anyone can guide me how to create this scenario with dynamic dropdownlist, so I can generate any number of dropdowns & fill it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a placeholder control on your web page and then create the new dropdown and add it to the placeholder like so:

```
private void AddDropDown(){
  var dl = new DropDownList();
  dl.ID="empDDL";
  dl.DataSource = list;
  dl.DataBind();
  myPlaceholer.Controls.Add(dl);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You use ASP.Net cascade dropdownlist. This example

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: In my case, No. of dropdownlist is not fixed.